# Excel Column to a Text file just "," between the values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel file with 10 columns,lets say i want to have all the data from column 1 need to appear just with a simple comma.. how can i do that
like

Processor Type
Intel i3
Intel I5
Intel I7
AMD FX

to something like => Intel i3,Intel I5,Intel I7,AMD FX

Is it possible,if yes how?

Comment: if you have a specific pattern then it is possible

Comment: Do you want the data in the 10 columns to be in 1 column with a comma separating them?

Answer (score 0):

If `Processor Type` is in A1, copy A2 to K2, enter `=K2&","&A3` in K3 and copy K3 down to suit.